# itextpdf - Calculating Avaliable Size for Image in Landscape

Tags: java, itext, landscape

I am trying to add an image to my PDF document in landscape and trying to calculate the available space is getting confusing (does X become Y and vise versa). I have some text at the top of the page and I want to use the rest of the space for the image. I have rotated the document but I can't figure out how to find the available space to use to position and resize my image. Can someone help? TIA.

Comment: Depending on your exact code, there may or may not be anything to think of. As you don't show your code, though, we can hardly tell.

Comment: @mkl Wt Riker used the last three characters he could type to inform us that he suffered from a [Transient Ischemic Attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_ischemic_attack). Our deepest sympathy. We hope you recover soon and share some code when you dom

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't post any code because I don't have any yet. If you really need my code, as far as I got in my thinking is 'image.setAbsolutePosition(???f, ???f);' I don't know how to calculate the x and y values. or which direction x and y represent with rotation.

Comment: Bruno: Sorry for bothering to ask a question. Your reply was very helpful and thoughtful.